# Disable click event on one td - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using onClick event function on row (tr) to show a modal.
I want to make all td of row open Bootstrap Modal except the last td with class is " clickable-td ".

html table :

```
    <tr OnClick="DisplayEnterOrderModal(this.id)" id="12" > 
         <td>12</td>
         <td>12</td>
         <td>147</td>
         <td>12345</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td class="clickable-td" >
             <div class="btn-group">
                <i class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                   ariaexpanded="false"><span class="caret" ></i>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu">
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Détails</a>
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Annuler</a>
                           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Eliminer</a>
                     </div>
                 </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$(".clickable-td").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you this work for me :), but  I want  to keep showingthe dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that works for me :)

```
 $(".clickable-td").on("click", function(e){
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();

            });
```